# Dynamo powered by motorcycle to charge a battery

Tags: battery-charging, dynamo

Hello and apologies if someone has asked this, I didn't see a question quite along these lines.
If you have an electric motorcycle, is it possible to have a dynamo attached to the bike that will charge a battery, so that when you need to stop for a recharge of the bike, you have a charged-up battery to do it from?  Would a battery that could do that be too big to lug on a bike?

IF the battery has to be huge, or multiple, could you instead do this with, say, a stripped-down truck with a group of batteries in the bed?

Not surprisingly, I'm watching 'Long Way Up' and seeing them struggle with the short range/recharging necessities of traveling on electric motorcycles.

Comment: No, that is a perpetual motion machine. You can't use the motorcycle battery to power the motor that turn the wheels, and use energy in that rotation both move the bike AND charge the battery up to the same level it was before. If you could, you would produce more energy than what you put in and cycle it through again to produce even more energy until you had infinite energy.

Comment: If you were coasting down a hill then you could use that to recharge, but that begs the question where you got the energy to get to the top of the hill in the first place. If you rode up the hill, then no because you spent just as much energy getting there (in reality more) than you will get from recharging. If you pushed it up the hill yourself, then yes because you took energy from yourself to recharge the battery. But you aren't a perpetual motion machine either so you would travel farther, faster, with less energy ditching the motor cycle and walking than pushing it up hill Or use a bike.

Comment: This is also why an electric car doesn't get infinite mileage if you install a dynamo. The alternator in a gas car is there because gasoline has more energy than a battery but your electrical devices don't run directly off gasoline.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it proposes a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: Running downhill, its motor and regular battery can do this, if the motor controller permits it. But on the flat or uphill, just no. (There is one dump truck at a mine that never needs charging. It climbs the mountain empty, and comes back down full, and much heavier)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ahhh. That's neat. So the increased weight on the way down always gave it enough extra potential energy to make up for both the losses on the way up and the charging losses on the way down? What was the reason for an electric dump truck was chosen anyways?

Comment: Why not just cut out the middleman and connect the dynamo directly to the e-bike's main battery so that you charge it while you ride! Then it'll never run out!! ;)

Comment: @DKNguyen Why? To save 22000 gallons of diesel a year! https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/infrastructure/a28748306/worlds-largest-electric-vehicle-dump-truck/

Comment: @BrianDrummond I guess what I'm asking is, was it purposely chosen to be electric to operate the uphill and downhill like that? Or was it chosen to be electric for some other reason and that regen operation was a happy coincidence?

Comment: I believe it was deliberate. The article suggests it was a custom build for that specific role, by replacing a 23 litre diesel from a commercial product with a 600kWh battery etc.

Comment: No, I'm not asking if you can run the bike off a battery that you're charging as you run it. I'm asking if you can *recharge* the bike (stopped) with a battery that was charged by the engine, with a dynamo, while you used it.  You could initially charge the bike from a home or recharging point, but then you would have the batter to recharge from if, for instance, you found yourself too far from a recharging point.

Answer (score 3):

[Perpetual motion machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) are impossible no matter how clever you think you are and how complex you can build them.

In your case, the dynamo will impose an additional load to the motorcycle motor and additional consumption from the battery. And, because you lose some energy as heat at any conversion stage, you will in fact get LESS mileage.

Sorry, that's how our universe works. You may as well try some different universe, but I am skeptic - the same laws of thermodynamics that make perpetual motion impossible actually make possible our life as we know it, among other things.

A sane electric or hybrid vehicle actually does use a dynamo process to charge the battery when decelerates or keeps a constant speed downhill. The motor is just switched to dynamo mode. Electric motors are quite easy to be used as generators. That's how the unneeded (at the moment) kinetic energy is harvested for future use. This is called "regenerative braking" (in contrast to frictional braking where the unneeded kinetic energy is simply wasted as heat).

Comment: You can also haul around a small amount of fuel and run a tiny little engine to turn your generator to recharge your battery, but at some point you might as well just use an engine to directly burn the fuel to spin the wheels since that is more efficient when you cut out the middleman. Or make a generator that operates off wood or whatever you can find laying around to burn

Answer (score 0):

Most EVs including bikes already recover 'spare energy' from motion through 'regenerative braking'. The kinetic energy stored is turned into electricity by the motor acting as a motor-generator when braking. No need for anything else at all.

There's a video from Bjorn Nyland on youtube showing how he recovered much of the energy used driving his MG ZS EV up some mountains when descending. It's nowhere like 100% efficient though.